# Is it possible to use Cocoa classes in an app that runs on Linux

Tags: objective-c, linux, cocoa

I am need to parse a pdf file.  I would like to use objective-c and Cocoa classes to do so, but I need the resulting application to run on Linux.  Is this possible?  My experience to Objective-C revolves around the iPhone so I'm relatively new to Cocoa.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cocoa is Mac and iPhone only, but you could use GNUstep, which is based off the same OpenStep Objective-C API as Cocoa, and PopplerKit for PDF reading.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to GNUstep, there's [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/) which cross-compiles from Xcode running on a Mac. If you can develop on Xcode, then it's an option.

Comment: Isn't Cocotron mainly focused on Windows, though?

Comment: @Chuck that's its primary focus, but it's got runtime support for Linux and Slowlaris, too.

Answer (score 1):

No, Cocoa is specific to Mac.  You can use Objective C on Linux, but I doubt there's much library support.  You might have better luck finding a PDF parser for Linux (ghostscript might have libraries) that also works on Mac.